# Converting System::IntPtr to HINSTANCE

Tags: c++-cli

I'm grabbing the HINSTANCE of a c# form using:

```
IntPtr hinstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]);
```

I'm then trying to pass it on to a C++/CLI component. I'm pretty sure this is a dumb question, but how in C++ CLI do you convert from an IntPtr to an HINSTANCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `ToPointer()` on it, you'll get a `void*`. That should be assignable to an `HINSTANCE`.